# How to use MongoDB in android?

Tags: android, mongodb, mongodb-java

MongoDB should be supported on Android since 2.9.0([link](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10006&version=11124)). I have downloaded 2.11.3 MongoDB java driver and set a simple code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(hostname, port);
db = mongo.getDB(dbname);

CommandResult lastError = db.getLastError();
if (!lastError.ok()) {
    throw new ConnectException("Error connecting to MongoDB: " + lastError.getErrorMessage());
}
Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

for (String s : colls) {
    Log.w("sd", s);
}
```

However, I get there messages when I run:

```
01-18 19:47:39.173: I/dalvikvm(25567): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean, referenced from method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>
01-18 19:47:39.183: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: unable to resolve static method 6785: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getRuntimeMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean;
01-18 19:47:39.183: D/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0071
01-18 19:47:39.293: I/dalvikvm(25567): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.<init>
01-18 19:47:39.293: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: unable to resolve static method 6784: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-18 19:47:39.293: D/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
01-18 19:47:39.293: E/dalvikvm(25567): Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.createObjectName
01-18 19:47:39.293: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1058 (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;) in Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
01-18 19:47:39.293: D/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
01-18 19:47:39.303: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1055 (Ljavax/management/MalformedObjectNameException;)
01-18 19:47:39.303: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x6
01-18 19:47:39.303: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;.createObjectName (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/management/ObjectName;
01-18 19:47:39.303: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0006
01-18 19:47:39.303: W/dalvikvm(25567): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;.createObjectName (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/management/ObjectName;
01-18 19:47:39.303: W/dalvikvm(25567): Verifier rejected class Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
```

and also NetworkOnMainThreadException in `db.getLastError()`.

Comment: Google `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: @Ahmad I know, I should put it in another thread, but will these dalvikvm warnings fix too?

Comment: Hmm seems like you're having the same problem like described in [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-295) thread

Comment: @Ahmad yeah, but it says it was fixed in 2.9.0, I have downloaded 2.11.3